# class listed in the persistence.xml file but not mapped

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence.xml

I have listed my class in persistence.xml but mapped class is not recognized inside.

```
I tried <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
```

But no luck.

My persistence.xml file

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="advertiserAPI" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>com.advertiser.model.Application</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://host:port/DB" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.autoReconnect" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="password"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.validator.apply_to_ddl" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size" value="16"/>
            <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class" value="thread"/>
            </properties>
        </persistence-unit>
    </persistence>
```

Test class file

```
    package com.advertiser.model.test;

    import java.util.List;

    import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
    import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
    import javax.persistence.Persistence;
    import javax.persistence.Query;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;

    import org.junit.Test;

    import com.advertiser.model.Application;

    public class ApplicationTest {

        @Test
        public void listAll() throws ServletException {
            EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("advertiserAPI");

            try {
                EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
                Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT id FROM Application");
                System.out.println("query " + query);

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStacktrace();
            } 
        }
    }
```

Application class has following

```
package com.advertiser.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.apache.commons.lang.builder.ToStringBuilder;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Entity;
import static org.apache.commons.lang.builder.ToStringStyle.MULTI_LINE_STYLE;

@Entity
@Table(name = "applications")
public class Application {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name", length = 255)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "host", length = 255, nullable = false)
    private String host;

    @Column(name = "app_type", columnDefinition = "TINYINT")
    private String appType;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "advertiser_id")
    private Integer advertiserId;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getHost() {
        return host;
    }

    public void setHost(String host) {
        this.host = host;
    }

    public String getAppType() {
        return appType;
    }

    public void setAppType(String appType) {
        this.appType = appType;
    }

    public Integer getAdvertiserId() {
        return advertiserId;
    }

    public void setAdvertiserId(Integer advertiserId) {
        this.advertiserId = advertiserId;
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove the useless catch block from your test, and post the full stack trace of the exception.

Comment: It should be SELECT a.id FROM Application a

Comment: @Koitoer Again getting same error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Application is not mapped [select a.id FROM Application a]

Comment: Remove try catch block as @JBNizet said and paste the stacktrace

Comment: The table name is "applications".

Comment: @RAM: JPQL never uses table names.

Comment: Also, show us the complete code of your entity, from the package statement to the last curly brace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have annotated your class with `@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity` instead of annotating it with `@javax.persistence.Entity.`

Comment: Thanks for the note. I changed as you said. But getting error as javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to build entity manager factory

Comment: Then ask another question, providing the code, configuration, and the complete stack trace of the exception.

Comment: Thank uuuuuuu. I Changed annotation with javax.persistence.Entity and asked to do some more changes. Now its working great. :[